# How to emit data only to one client in Meteor streams

Tags: meteor

I am building a realtime game with Meteor streams. I need to update only one client - send a room ID from server. Users are not logged in so Meteor.userId() is null and therefore I can't use this: http://arunoda.github.io/meteor-streams/communication-patterns.html#streaming_private_page

There is only one URL (homepage) where all things happen. So I don't use any URL parameters for room. Everything is on the server.

I have tried to use Meteor.uuid() instead of Meteor.userId() but uuid is changed after each emit (which is strange).

In socket.io I would do this:

```
//clients is an array of connected socket ids
var clientIndex = clients.indexOf(socket.id);
io.sockets.socket(clients[clientIndex]).emit('message', 'hi client');
```

Is there any way to do this in Meteor streams or Meteor itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this can be easily done if you decided to use database, but I guess it is not the best option if you have a large number of clients.

So another way to achieve this - without database - is to make a good use of the Meteor's `publish/subscribe` mechanism. Basically the way it could work is the following:

```
 1. client asks server for a communication token (use Meteor.methods)
 2. client subscribes to some (abstract) data set using that token
 3. server publishes the required data based on the received token
```

So you will need to define a method - say `getToken` - on the server that generates tokens for new users (since you don't want to use `accounts`). This could be something more or less like this:

```
var clients = {}

Meteor.methods({
  getToken: function () {
    var token;
    do {
      token = Random.id();
    } while (clients[token]);
    clients[token] = {
      dependency: new Deps.Dependency(),
      messages: [],
    };
    return token;
  },
});
```

A new client will need to ask for token and subscribe to the data stream:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  Meteor.call('getToken', function (error, myToken) {
    // possibly use local storage to save the token for further use
    if (!error) {
      Meteor.subscribe('messages', myToken);
    }
  });
});
```

On the server you will need to define a custom publish method:

```
Meteor.publish('messages', function (token) {
  var self = this;

  if (!clients[token]) {
    throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Access deniend.');
  }

  send(token, 'hello my new client');

  var handle = Deps.autorun(function () {
    clients[token].dependency.depend();
    while (clients[token].messages.length) {
      self.added('messages', Random.id(), {
        message: clients[token].messages.shift()
      });
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function () {
    handle.stop();
  });
});
```

and the `send` function could defined as follows:

```
var send = function (token, message) {
  if (clients[token]) {
    clients[token].messages.push(message);
    clients[token].dependency.changed();
  }
}
```

That's a method I would use. Please check if it works for you.

Comment: In general... YES. However, you will need to be a little more careful with your `autorun` callbacks. I believe they sometimes need to be wrapped with `Meteor.bindEnvironment` in order to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think using Meteor.onConnection() like a login would enable you to do what you want pretty easily in a publish function.

Something like this:

```
Messages = new Meteor.Collection( 'messages' );

if ( Meteor.isServer ){
   var Connections = new Meteor.Collection( 'connections' );
   Meteor.onConnection( function( connection ){
     var connectionMongoId = Connections.insert( connection );
     //example Message
     Message.insert( {connectionId: connection.id, msg: "Welcome"}); 

     //remove users when they disconnect
     connection.onClose = function(){
       Connections.remove( connectionMongoId );
     };
   });

   Meteor.publish( 'messages', function(){
     var self = this;
     var connectionId = self.connection.id;
     return Messages.find( {connectionId: connectionId});
   });

}

if ( Meteor.isClient ){
  Meteor.subscribe('messages');

  Template.myTemplate.messages = function(){
    //show all user messages in template
    return Messages.find();
  };
}
```

I have used database backed collections here since they are the default but the database is not necessary. Making Messages a collection makes the reactive publishing easy whenever a new message is inserted.

One way that this is different from streams is that all the messages sent to all clients will end up being kept in server memory as it tries to keeps track of all data sent.  If that is really undesirable then you could use a Meteor.method so send data instead and just use publish to notify a user a new message is available so call the method and get it.

Anyway this is how I would start.